# What is `s` in the output of the `loess` function in R? The coefficient of determination?

Tags: r, loess

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/loess) does not detail the ouput of the function

```r
model <- loess(cyl ~ disp, data = mtcars)
model$s
[1] 0.5679605
```

EDIT : `s` is the Residual Standard Error apparently

Comment: `summary(model)` gives `Residual Standard Error: 0.568`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the object definition](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/6.0.0/doc/html/Language_Reference/stats/loess.object.html), it's the the residual standard error for the model.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *official* documentation for the content of a `loess` object.  If you look at the [source code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-4-2-branch/src/library/stats/man/loess.Rd) of the help page for function `loess`, you'll even see:

```
\value{
  An object of class \code{"loess"}.% otherwise entirely unspecified (!)
}
```

As others have suggested, the `print` method contains clues:

```r
> stats:::print.loess
function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), ...) 
{
    if (!is.null(cl <- x$call)) {
        cat("Call:\n")
        dput(cl, control = NULL)
    }
    cat("\nNumber of Observations:", x$n, "\n")
    cat("Equivalent Number of Parameters:", format(round(x$enp, 
        2L)), "\n")
    cat("Residual", if (x$pars$family == "gaussian") 
        "Standard Error:"
    else "Scale Estimate:", format(signif(x$s, digits)), "\n")
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x11f8e7390>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

So `s` is *either* a residual standard error or a residual scale estimate, depending on the value of argument `family` passed to `loess`.

P.S.: I was curious, so I did a quick scan of Chapter 8 of the [White Book](https://www.routledge.com/Statistical-Models-in-S/Chambers-Hastie/p/book/9780412830402), the original reference for the `loess` function now in R.  It describes the theory and usage in detail, but it doesn't explicitly define all of the components of a `loess` object as I thought it might.  Oh well.